# Customer Login and Registration broken

Tags: magento

i have a problem with magento customerlogin and registration on frontend. If someone wants to login and enter his logininformation and submit this, magento redirects to index (or sometimes it remains on the loginform) and nothing happens. It's not possible to see the Customeraccount. Same with registration.

Back-End Login works

Anyone a solution for that?
Thanks.

Comment: yes. In the Magentologs theres nothing. apache code is 302 Moved Temporarily

Answer (score 0):

Before looking further, make sure you clear browser cookies, delete sessions under /var/sessions, and clear the magento cache.

You can also try increasing the cookie timeout in ADMIN >> CONFIG >> WEB >> SESSION COOKIE MANAGEMENT.

If this is on a production site, be sure you want to remove sessions as there could be someone about to checkout.